# How to create Python script using FIFO from two different users

Tags: python

For security reasons, I am using this method to replicate channels 
from satellite server to DMZ sat server:

Run this command as root on satellite server
`[root@servername satellite]# tar -cv sync | gzip -3 > /tmp/file.fifo`

On second shell,
`[My_username@servername satellite]# cat /tmp/file.fifo |ssh $jump_server  ssh remote_dmz_server tar -xz -C /var/satellite/dump`

Then on the remote dmz sat server
`satellite-sync --mount-point=/var/satellite/dump/sync/  -c "channel name"`

I want to write  a script that will automate the channels sync using those commands
preferably in Python or Bash, the challenge that I see is, how to write a script
that will run with my username, do `su -c`, and run the commands as root, all in one script.

If possible, please advise, thank you!

Comment: What have you tried thus far? We can certainly help your out if you have an issue of sorts. But we would like you to show some effort in solving it yourself first. But you should check out http://superuser.com/questions/170866/how-to-run-a-cron-job-as-a-specific-user